# Why am I receiving 401 Unauthroized from CardPoint API when using test credentials

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am trying to test CardConnect's API, and whenever I make a request to https://fts.cardconnect.com:6443/rest/auth I receive an unauthorized response. I've tried rolling back the version of rest sharp to an older version, but that didn't seem to help.

Here is the main function.

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            // Send an Auth Transaction request
            String retref = authTransaction();
            // Void transaction
            voidTransaction(retref);
        }
```

This is where I'm building my JObject to send in the request.

```
public static String authTransaction()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nAuthorization Request");

            // Create Authorization Transaction request
            JObject request = new JObject();
            // Merchant ID
            request.Add("merchid", "496160873888");
            // Card Type
            request.Add("accttype", "VI");
            // Card Number
            request.Add("account", "4444333322221111");
            // Card Expiry
            request.Add("expiry", "0914");
            // Card CCV2
            request.Add("cvv2", "776");
            // Transaction amount
            request.Add("amount", "100");
            // Transaction currency
            request.Add("currency", "USD");
            // Order ID
            request.Add("orderid", "12345");
            // Cardholder Name
            request.Add("name", "Test User");
            // Cardholder Address
            request.Add("Street", "123 Test St");
            // Cardholder City
            request.Add("city", "TestCity");
            // Cardholder State
            request.Add("region", "TestState");
            // Cardholder Country
            request.Add("country", "US");
            // Cardholder Zip-Code
            request.Add("postal", "11111");
            // Return a token for this card number
            request.Add("tokenize", "Y");

            // Create the REST client
            CardConnectRestClient client = new CardConnectRestClient(ENDPOINT, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

            // Send an AuthTransaction request
            JObject response = client.authorizeTransaction(request);

            foreach (var x in response)
            {
                String key = x.Key;
                JToken value = x.Value;
                Console.WriteLine(key + ": " + value.ToString());
            }

            return (String)response.GetValue("retref");
        }
```

From here, this is where the object is finally sent.

```
public JObject authorizeTransaction(JObject request)
        {
            return (JObject)send(ENDPOINT_AUTH, OPERATIONS.PUT, request);
        }
 private Object send(String endpoint, OPERATIONS operation, JObject request)
        {
            // Create REST client
            RestClient client = new RestClient(url);

            // Set authentication credentials
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password);

            // Create REST request
            RestRequest rest = null;
            switch (operation)
            {
                case OPERATIONS.PUT: rest = new RestRequest(endpoint, Method.Put); break;
                case OPERATIONS.GET: rest = new RestRequest(endpoint, Method.Get); break;
                case OPERATIONS.POST: rest = new RestRequest(endpoint, Method.Post); break;
                case OPERATIONS.DELETE: rest = new RestRequest(endpoint, Method.Delete); break;
            }

            rest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            rest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            String data = (request != null) ? request.ToString() : "";
            rest.AddParameter("application/json", data, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            RestResponse response = client.ExecuteAsync(rest).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            JsonTextReader jsreader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(response.Content));

            try
            {
                return new JsonSerializer().Deserialize(jsreader);
            }
            catch (JsonReaderException jx)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

For the most part, this is just the file provided by Cardpoint on their Github page, so it's got me stumped as to why this wouldn't work.

I have also tried changing my credentials and manually adding the Authorization header. The documentation mentions that this would happen because it received invalid credentials. However, using the same credentials in postman returns a 200 response.

Comment: Did you look at documentation on vendors webpage : https://cardconnect.com/developers

Comment: Yes, that's where I got the test credentials from.

Comment: Does it work from Postman?

Comment: Yes it works from Postman

Comment: The default http headers in c# are different from Postman.  The best way of solving is to make the c# headers look exactly the same as Postman.  Sometime changing the UserAgent (the header that specifies the browser helps) since some webpages to not accept all browsers.

Comment: I can suggest reading the RestSharp docs. Every second question about RestSharp is about the same thing. https://restsharp.dev/support/#content-type

Comment: So I've removed the ContentType header, and it's sending a 500 error now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. Typically RestSharp handles setting the content-type, but CardConnect is one of the times it has to be set manually. So the problem that I was having was how I was setting the body parameter. I had to change

```
 rest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        rest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        String data = (request != null) ? request.ToString() : "";
        rest.AddParameter("application/json", data, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        RestResponse response = client.ExecuteAsync(rest).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

to

```
 String data = (request != null) ? request.ToString() : "";
        rest.AddBody(data,"application/json");
        rest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        var response =  await client.ExecutePutAsync(rest);
```

Once I did this my requests started going through without issue.